# Time complexity when have composite data type such as tuple or pair?

Tags: c++, dictionary, unordered

In Hash map data structure such as unordered_map in C++:

```
 unodered_map<char, int> mp = { {'a', 10}, {'b', 20} };
 if (mp.find('a') != mp.end())
     cout << "found you";
```

we know find() method takes constant time. but if I have composite data as the key:

```
 unodered_map<tuple<char, string, int>, int> mp = { {'a', "apple", 10}, 100};
 if (mp.find( {'a', "apple", 10} ) != mp.end())
     cout << "found you";
```

Will the find() method still take constant time? how to evaluate the time complexity now?

Comment: What we actually know is that `find` is constant on average, and linear in the size of the map in the worst case.

Comment: Regardless of the internal implementation of `find()` (see the answers below), complex data structure can be easily reduced to plain one - e.g. by serializing to a bytestream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the more bytes of data in the key, the longer the hash function will take to generate a value (though some hash functions do not look at every byte, and can therefore have reduced big-O complexity).  There might be more or less bytes because the tuple has more values, or some element in the tuple is variable sized (like a `std::string`).  Similarly, with more bytes, it generally takes longer to test two keys for equality, which is another crucial operation for hash tables.

So, you could say your table's operations scale linearly with the size of the keys - O(K) - all other things being equal.

But, more often, you're interested in comparing how the performance of any given insert/erase/find compares with how long it would take in another type of container, and in many other types of containers the performance tends to degrade as you add more and more keys.  That's where people describe hash tables as generally having amortised average-case O(1) operational complexity, whereas e.g. balanced binary trees may be O(logN) where N is the number of elements stored.

There are some other considerations, such as that operations in a balanced binary tree tend to involve comparisons (i.e. `key1 < key2`), which may be short-circuited at the first differing byte, whereas hash functions tend to have to process all bytes in the key.

Now, if in your problem domain, the size of keys may vary widely, then it's meaningful to think in terms of O(K) complexity, but if the size of keys tends to hover around the same typical range - regardless of the number of keys you're storing, then the table property is reasonably expressed as O(1) - removing the near-constant multiplicative factor.

---

I think it helps to consider a familiar analogy.  If you have 100 friends' names stored in your phone address book, or you have millions of names from a big city's phone book, the average length of names is probably pretty similar, so you could very reasonably talk about the big-O efficiency of your data structure in terms of "N" while ignoring the way it shrinks or grows with name length "K".

On the other hand, if you're thinking about storing arbitrary-length keys in a hash table, and some people might try to put XML versions of  encyclopaedias, while others store novels, poems, or individual words, then there's enough variety in key length that it makes sense to describe the varying performance in terms of K.

Similarly true if you were storing say information on binary video data, and someone was considering using the raw binary video data as the hash table key: some 8k HDR and hours long, and others tiny animated gifs.  (A better approach would be to generate a 64+ bit hash of the video data and use that for a key, which for most practical purposes will be reliably unique; if dealing with billions of videos use 128 bit).

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical running time is not in fact constant. The running time is constant only on avarage, given reasonable use cases.

A [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is used in the implementation. If you implement a (good) hash function for your tuple that runs in constant time, the [asymptotic running time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity) of `find` is unaffected.